# PhpStorm and gulp LiveReload: how to make them work together?

Tags: gulp, phpstorm, gulp-watch, livereload

My goal is to run gulp LiveReload with PhpStorm (LiveEdit is not good for me since I use complex framework)

I have created this `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch('*', function() {
        livereload();
        console.log('changed !')
    });
});
```

I run it in PhpStorm

```
[02:20:02] Starting 'watch'...
```

I've installed the LiveReload Chrome plugin and connected it: (it says connected) 
[image]

Any time I make a change on a file, I got a 'changed' message in PhpStorm's terminal. But browser is not refreshed automatically.

Comment: Well ... try launching it (your gulp task) from outside from PhpStorm (not using PhpStorm's built-in Terminal functionality) -- any difference? So far I do not see any place where PhpStorm could be a problem.

Comment: yes: it worked from outside phoStorm